# What is "induction on complexity of formula"

Tags: model-theory, filters

The fundamental theorem of ultraproducts

Given a language $L$ and a family of models $M_i$ of $L$ and ultrafilter $\mathcal U$ on $I$ and $\varphi$ a formula of $L$ then 
$$ \prod_{i \in I}A_i/\mathcal U \models \varphi(s_0/_{\mathcal U}, \dots, s_n/_{\mathcal U}) \iff \{i \in I : \varphi (s_0(i), \dots, s_n (i))\}\in \mathcal U$$

Is proved by induction on the complexity of $\varphi$. I expect the proof to do atomic formula case first. Atomic formula is formula of form $\varphi = (t_1 = t_2)$ or of form $\varphi = R(t_1, \dots , t_n)$ where $t_i$ are term. But the proofs for example [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=uiHq0EmaFp0C&lpg=PA217&ots=f0KUrDCmYZ&dq=fundamental%20theorem%20of%20ultraproducts%20proof&pg=PA217#v=onepage&q=fundamental%20theorem%20of%20ultraproducts%20proof&f=false) prove something about terms not atomic formula. Can someone explain me please what is it we need to show if not atomic formula case first? Why terms?

Answer (score 1):

The construction of terms usually proceeds through the following recursive definition:

- Any variable $x$ is a term;
- Any constant $c$ is a term;
- For an $n$-ary function symbol $f$ and terms $t_1,\ldots, t_n$, $f(t_1,\ldots,t_n)$ is a term.

(Some texts define constants as nullary function symbols, but this does not guarantee that this special case does not require special attention -- i.e. it is not trivial that the induction proof for function symbols of positive arity carries over to nullary function symbols.)

---

So in order to prove a statement $P(t)$ about terms $t$ by induction on the complexity, one needs to verify that each of these constructions is suitably well-behaved with regard to the formation rules.

That is, we need to verify that $P(x), P(c)$ for $x$ a variable, $c$ a constant, and that $P(t_1),\ldots, P(t_n)$ imply $P(f(t_1,\ldots,t_n))$.

Now why would we want to have such statements $P$? Well, a useful example of a statement $P$ about terms could be verifying your initial statement for the case $\varphi = (t_1 = t_2)$!

---

In conclusion, proving something about terms is entirely *different* from proving something for formulae. Therefore, they call for different approaches, and as such require a different basis for their "structural induction".

Comment: While true, the answer does not address the *specific* case that troubles the OP.

Comment: But the referenced proof _does_ in fact start the part (iii), or more accurately, (ii), at the atomic formulae. It is only preceded by a proof of (i), which is needed to establish (ii) for atomic formulae, see the middle of p.218. I couldn't see where OP went astray, and this was the only moderately logical thing I could come up with. I'd appreciate some feedback from OP. @dolan

Comment: Is $P$ the $\varphi$? It is not clear what is first step of proof. When atomic case then show $t=t'$ and $Rt$ for term $t,t'$. Then cases should be constant $c=c'$, variable $v=v'$ and function $f(t) = f'(t)$. But (i) in link is not show it. It show something else.

Comment: In this case, $P(t)$ can be viewed as e.g. the statement "the atomic case holds for $Rt$"; we could also have $P(t,t')$ stating "the atomic case holds for $t=t'$". In short, $P(t)$ may be anything one would like to say about $t$ (even "$t$ is green", although I wouldn't know how to prove that).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, when doing induction on the complexity of *formulae*, you need to do some sort of induction on the complexity of *terms* first in order to prove your basis cases for the induction on the complexity of formulae. That's what Chang & Keisler, the book you referenced, do. Their theorem has parts (i), (ii), and (iii); part (i) is just a statement about terms, proven by induction on the complexity of terms, and part (ii) is the part you're concerned about, which is proven by induction on the complexity of formulae using part (i) to get the basis case rolling. So you *are* doing the atomic case first, but it's just that in order to do the atomic case, you need a separate argument, which happens to be an argument via induction on the complexity of terms.

Comment: Is (i) the proof of well-definedness of terms definition?