# Prove that every $L$-term has an odd number of symbols

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

We're talking about first-order logic.

Assume that we have $3$ symbols in a language $L$:

$o$ which is a constant symbol, $f$ which is a function which takes $2$ variables as input and $g$ which is another function which takes $4$   variables as its input.

**By induction on the complexity of $L$-terms**, Prove that every $L$-term has an odd number of symbols.

Note : I don't understand the part that talks about odd number of symbols.  I also don't know what does "complexity of $L$-terms" mean.  Actually, its been a while since i had "logic class" and i don't remember how we proved such these things. Now, I'm facing this question and i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: See [what-is-induction-on-complexity-of-formula](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399295/what-is-induction-on-complexity-of-formula) and [Structural induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

You have to use the inductive definition of *term* :

> every *variable* is a term;
>
> every *constant* is a term;
>
> if $t_1$ and $t_2$ are terms and $f$ is a binary *function* symbol, then $f(t_1,t_2)$ is a term.

The first two clauses of the definition are the *base* case and the third clause is the *inductive* step.

Comment: So, can i say that "because $f(t_1,t_2)$ has three symbols  ( $f,t_1,t_2$ ), so, the inductive step is proved" ?

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade - NO. (i) *basis* both variables and constants are one-symbol terms: so Ok. (ii) inductive step : ssume that $t_1$ and $t_2$ are odd-symbols expressions, with lenght $2k_1+1$ and $2k_2+1$ respectively; then the lenght of $f t_1 t_2$ is $1+(2k_1+1)+(2k_2+1)=2(k_1+k_2+1)+1$ and it's Ok.